# Passing a method into another method in Rust

Tags: rust

I have some code with a basic structure as shown below.
`apply_bin_operation` is supposed to call the method passed into `op`. The method referred to by `op` must have access to the instance's fields.
I've tried using closures and FnMut as well as several other things but since I'm programming in this language for the first time, I'm lost as to what is the correct way. How would one achieve this?

```
struct ECC{
    a: NumType,
    b: NumType
}    //has some fields

impl ECC {

 fn apply_bin_operation(
        &self,
        p1_maybe: Option<Point>,
        p2_maybe: Option<Point>,
        op: &dyn Fn(Point, Point) -> Point,    //is this the correct way to take such a method as parameter?
    ) -> Option<Point> {
        if let Some(p1) = p1_maybe {
            if let Some(p2) = p2_maybe {
                return Some(op(p1, p2));
            }
            return None;
        }
        return None;
    }

fn addition_util(&self, p1: Point, p2: Point) -> Point {
        ...    // method that applies operations on p1 and p2 w.r.t the instance's fields a and b
    }

fn caller(&self, p: Option<Point>) -> Point {
    self.apply_bin_operation(p, p, &self.addition_util)    //how should the method be passed?
}
}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because there are quite a few unrelated issues in your code, but is this what you are looking for: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=872c054e1893718d295c90559ab72ead)?

Comment: @Jmb I guess thats it. It just makes not really sense on making such I thing I think. But then again, we are maybe missing some extent of the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a closure to another Rust function then you likely want to do something like this:

```
fn test1<F:Fn(u32) -> u32>(input:u32, op:F) -> u32 {
    op(input)
}

fn test2<F>(input:u32, op:F) -> u32
where F:Fn(u32) -> u32
{
    op(input)
}
```

Note that both forms are equivalent, just shuffling around where the trait bound for `F` is declared.

In your case you also want access to the fields of `ECC`. That can be accomplished by adding `Self` as an input to the closure:

```
struct S { a:u32, b:u32 }

impl S {
    fn s_method<F>(&self, input:u32, op:F) -> u32
    where F:Fn(&Self, u32) -> u32
    {
        op(self, input)
    }

    fn s_arg(&self, input:u32) -> u32 {
        self.a - self.b + input
    }
}
```

Finally, we can create and pass closures to these functions in the following ways:

```
fn main() {
    let s = S { a:2, b:1 };
    println!("{}", test1(0, |x| x));
    println!("{}", test2(0, &|x| x)); // notice we can pass by reference too
    println!("{}", s.s_method(10, |x, i| x.a + x.b + i));
    println!("{}", s.s_method(100, S::s_arg));
}
```

Notice in particular the last line, which is a complete example of what you are trying to do: A method (`s_arg`) of a struct (`S`) is passed as a closure to another method (`s_method`) of the same struct.

Closures will implement `Clone` and `Copy` if all of the captured variables do, so passing by reference or implicitly copying is a choice you have to make on a case-by-case basis.

As a side note, you only want to use trait objects (the `&dyn Fn ...` in your example) in two cases:

1. You need dynamic dispatch, i.e. you want to pick the method at runtime
2. You want to prevent monomorphization from causing binary bloat or long compile times. This case in particular is probably not going to cause you issues unless you're using a *lot* of distinct concrete closures. Even then, it is a tradeoff between the compile time cost of monomorphization and the runtime overhead of dynamic dispatch.

Here is a [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=50abaef1585d51fec351733989678aca) to the rust playground with the above code to play with.